# substring regex for first part of url

Tags: regex, postgresql, url, postgresql-8.4

I've got a large database of projects and issue trackers, some of which have urls.

I'd like to query it to figure out a list of urls for each project, but many have extra data I'd like to avoid.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
substring(tracker_extra_field_data.field_data FROM 'http://([^/]*).*')
```

Except some urls are https, and I'd like to capture that as well as the first sub directory.

For example, given the url:

```
https://dev.foo.com/bar/action/?param=val
```

I'd like the select to return:

```
https://dev.foo.com/bar/
```

Is there a semi-simple way to do this with substring/regex in pgsql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

`select substring('https://dev.foo.com/bar/action/?param=val' from '(https?://([^/]*/){1,2})');`

```
template1=# select substring('https://dev.foo.com/bar/action/?param=val' from '(https?://([^/]*/){1,2})');
        substring
-------------------------
 https://dev.foo.com/bar/
(1 row)

template1=# select substring('http://dev.foo.com/bar/action/?param=val' from '(https?://([^/]*/){1,2})');
       substring
------------------------
 http://dev.foo.com/bar/
```

Comment: +1 Since you had most of it first. Consider this [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!11/d41d8/46), though.

Comment: yeah My original I had the / optional.    (and Id didn't anchor the https.. if I use ` (https?://([^/]*/?){1,2})` it gets more.  OP asked for first directory as as well which is why went with the {1,2}.  but yep all depends on how normalized the data inside is.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Updated after I didn't read the Q properly at first.</sup>

Use the pattern

```
^https?://[^/]+(?:/[^/]+)?/?
```

`^` .. start of string
`?` .. zero or one atoms
`(?:)` .. non-capturing parens
`[^/]+` .. any character except `/`, 1 or more of them

This only accepts URLs starting with `http://` or `https://` (protocol header required).

[->SQLfiddle with a bigger test case.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!11/d41d8/46)