# Query for removing prefix and remove duplicates

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a table as follows:

```
    uri               | country
----------------------+--------
http://www.A.com      |   NL
http://www.A.com/sub  |   NL
https://www.B.com     |   NL
http://C.com          |   DL
```

I need a select query (including regex) to show distinct rows without uri.

```
Desired outcome:
    www.A.com      NL
    www.B.com      NL
    C.com          DL
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750657/substring-regex-for-first-part-of-url):

```
select distinct substring(uri from '(https?://([^/]*/){1,2})'),country from list;
```

But the regex cannot handle simple domain like: www.A.com 
It is only working for www.A.com/sub

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why is because `([^/]*/)` this part of the regex requires that your text ends with a `/`. Looking at your desired outcome, I think you should change your regex to `https?://([^/]*).*`

Comment: Thanks, based on that I tried  `select substring('https://dev.foo.com/sdfa' from '(https?://([^/]*){1,2})');` and it works to remove suffix from domain but it doesn't remove http:// from prefix. How is this?

Comment: You have 2 round brackets, so also 2 groups. The ones around the entire regex and the ones around `[^/]*`  Since you don't want to do anything with the outer brackets, you can drop them.

Comment: Ah you right, thank you so much. Here is the complete query: `select distinct substring(uri from 'https?://([^/]*).*'),country from list;`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by:

```
select distinct substring(uri from '.*://([^/]*)' ),country from list;
```